# On Android, what does "kill process" mean?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

While running a Compose codelab (basics), I encountered these sentences:

> Instead of using remember you can use rememberSaveable. This will save
> each state surviving configuration changes (such as rotations) and
> process death. ... Run, rotate, change to dark mode or kill the
> process. The onboarding screen is not shown unless you have previously
> exited the app.

My initial reaction to "process death" was that the author was referring to how Android will arbitrarily just kill an app process when it needs resources. I do not believe this is something a User can make happen, as opposed to exiting an app.

Then the author says "Run, rotate or kill the process" which makes me think there does exist a way for a User to kill the process without exiting the app. Is there a way to kill an app process using some gesture or recipe other than swiping to exit the app, or using force close from the Settings app?

A good answer to my question would allow me to either test my code using the supposed kill process mechanism or inform the author that the codelab documentation is a little loose and might be tightened up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're getting at is the difference between an app/activity/etc. being killed in a recoverable way vs. not.

Force stopping (not recoverable, state lost):

- Open Recents, swipe away the app
- Open Settings, force close the app
- Use adb: `adb shell am force-stop com.example.myapp`

Killing (recoverable, state retained):

- Move the app to the background and use adb: `adb shell am kill com.example.myapp`
- Enable the developer option "Don't keep activities," then navigate away from the activity

Comment: Ian, the first four bullet points are easily verifiable and correct. But the last one has me stumped on precisely what you mean by "navigate away from the activity" and how this applies to an app with a single activity. Other that that, you nailed it.

Comment: Navigate away from the activity means to change to displaying another activity. If you had multiple activities, switching from ActivityA to ActivityB means that ActivityA will be killed. In the case where you don't, you can instead press the home button. Since the launcher's activity is now displayed, your activity will be killed.

Answer (score 0):

kill process = when your activity is done and should be closed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately, not a good answer since it does not help to test the code and it does not help determine if the documentation is in error, which I believe to be the case.